# Inactive state of select in Opera

Tags: javascript, html, input, opera

I have a problem in Opera: when I `.select()` one input and after click on other input i'm doing `.select()` too. In all browsers I have correct behavior (one input has selected content, but other - not).

But in Opera I have following: https://skitch.com/invis89/e1tue/screen-shot-2012-09-10-at-4.45.34-pm

And it's only when I'm trying to switch between fields via mouse. When I'm switching using tab key - everything is OK and I've assumed that some mouse event is doing that.. but what exactly - don't know.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So Opera indicates an "inactive", greyed-out selection when a script creates one. Is this a problem?

Comment: yep, it's interesting thing and I'm trying to understand what's really going on.

Comment: Well, that's what's going on. The script creates a selection in that input, so Opera indicates that there is a selection there even though the input doesn't have focus. This makes sense to me, but maybe just because I'm used to it :)

Comment: and you assume that multiple selections on the page is correct behavior?

Comment: I assume that's what you want to happen if you add a script creating those selections :)

Comment: Or - alternatively - other browsers lack the feature that shows inactive selections that your script has created in input elements. You seem to consider Opera's behaviour incorrect, which I don't understand. Why is this not a good way to do it, in your opinion?